# tableview cell not showing text from class

Tags: swift

trying to generate a simple tableview from a Class. If I make the cell = "A" it will print A's in all the cells just fine, but for this current code output it just shows a blank Table. What am I doing wrong? sorry self-learning newbie here.

```
import UIKit

class LinesViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var linesTableView: UITableView!
let cellID = "cell"
let lines = ["brown","red","blue"]

class Train  {
    var color: String = ""
    var line: String = ""

    init (color:String?, line:String?){
    }
}

let brownLine = Train(color: "brown", line: "Brown Line")
let redLine = Train(color: "red", line: "Red Line")
let blueLine = Train(color: "blue", line: "Blue Line")
var trains: [Train] = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    linesTableView.delegate = self
    linesTableView.dataSource = self
    trains = [brownLine,redLine,blueLine]
    //print (trains[1].line)

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return lines.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = linesTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellID, for: indexPath)

    let train = trains[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.text = train.line

    return cell
}
```

Comment: You forgot to assign the values in your `Train` initializer, so they're still empty strings.

Comment: Have you try just putting a fixed text to test first visual? Change this: cell.textLabel?.text = train.line for this: cell.textLabel?.text = "Hello" Also you are not initializing correctly your class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't assigning the passing values to your class data members.
Thats why they were always empty.

```
class Train  {
    var color: String = ""
    var line: String = ""

    init (color:String?, line:String?){
        self.color = color
        self.line = line
    }
}
```

Comment: ah thank you, that worked. The comments looked like they were correct, but syed's example showed me exactly how to properly initialize my class values